# What is pci=nobar in Ubuntu launch

Tags: boot, grub2, sound, touchpad, launcher

I bought a new laptop, a HP Omen 16 Transcend. I set up Ubuntu on dual boot but the only way I could get past the launcher loading screen (when you see a spinner and the Ubuntu logo) was to hit e when on “install or try Ubuntu” and then edit the iso Linux launcher line to have …splash pci=nobar.

I found the answer on Reddit here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/s/ZF1Xe45pOM

The problem is this now means my built in speaker and touchpad don’t work and there are various sleep issues. There’s a patch for some problems but not the speaker.

Can someone explain what this setting does exactly and advise on where I should go searching for these fixes.

I tried removing the nobar setting in grub after install but it just crashes on “malformed Msft vendor event”

Comment: The problem is that your hardware is not supported by the kernel. BAR stands for "Base Address Register". There is really nothing you can do about this until (if) the kernel supports your hardware.